# How to send notification to user when a record is added in the DB

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I'm developing an Android application , i have to develop an activity that contains a simple communications board .

The information that i want show are contained in a database , When the user started the activity the informations are downloaded , parsed and Showed to users.

Now i would implement a function That notify to the user When a new information is inserted in the db.

Now what that i don't understand is:

I need to implement a service that runs in background and polls the database and notify to the user when a information is inserted or can i use only the GMC (now FCM) ?

If i don't want use GCM there are another solution to do this ?

I have read some thread in stack overflow and there are different solution but i don't understand what is the best solution for my problem.

Comment: where is this database? on the local device? or online somewhere behind a webservice?

Comment: The database is online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking at a high-level, here's what I would do.

If I didn't want to use GCM then I would write my own service to make an http request to my backend web server to check if any new information is available.  If any new info is received save it to my local Android database and refresh the app.  I'd use Android's AlarmManager to start this service every so often (hourly, daily, whatever frequency I want).